# GoogleApiClient и Moxy

Tags: android, mvp

Архитектура приложения MVP на базе Moxy. Presenter должен получать данные долготы и ширины из модели и отдавать во View. Не могу додумать, как реализовать модель на базе GoogleApiClient, так как он требует context и какой класс должен реализовывать GoogleApiClient Callbacks?

Answer (score 2):

1. Стоит использовать `Context` аппликейшена. Его можно доставить двумя способами:

   - Заинжектить, используя dagger или ещё что-нибудь
   - Сделать метод `LocationPresenter.init(Context context)`, в котором вы сохраните `context` в локальное поле `LocationPresenter`. Только убедитесь, что вы устанавливаете контекст приложения, а не активити! Иначе будет утечка памяти. Для этого можно внутри `LocationPresenter` сохранять ссылку не на тот `context`, который пришел, а на `context.getApplicationContext()`.
2. В качестве GoogleApiClient Callbacks я бы сделал сам `LocationPresenter`. А при изменении локейшена, отправлял бы новые данные во view.
3. Если вам нужно, чтобы локейшен отслеживался сразу на нескольких экранах приложения, можете сделать этот presenter типа weak, и использовать его там, где нужно. Тогда, когда будут остановлены все activity, которые используют этот presetner, он будет уничтожен.
4. Отписываться от GoogleApiClient необходимо в методе `LocationPresetner.onDestroy()`.